# Cannot display widget on a window in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Im trying to run a widget, a simple rectangle that will go up and down in the GameWindow. However, when i run it i got the error " TypeError: descriptor 'bind' of 'kivy._event.EventDispatcher' object needs an argument" Can someone help ? Thanks in advance !

countdown.py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class GameWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GameWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Rect)

class Rect(Widget):
    velocity = ListProperty([10, 2])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Rect, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1/8)

    def update(self, *args):

        self.y += self.velocity[1]
        if self.y < 0 or (self.y + self.height) > 20:
            self.velocity[1] *= -1


kys = Builder.load_file("countdown.kv")

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

countdown.kv file

```
WindowManager:
    GameWindow:

<GameWindow>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: (42,15)
```

error that i got

```
TypeError: descriptor 'bind' of 'kivy._event.EventDispatcher' object needs an argument
```

Comment: change to `self.add_widget(Rect())`

Comment: Thank you ! The rectangle is displayed already. However, it is not moving tho according to my function.

Comment: I recommend you read your question, the question is aimed at solving the error generated by your code, and the duplicate explains the reason for the problem (also to clearly indicate how it applies to your case). If you have another question then I invite you to post a new question. On the other hand "Rect" is added to the widget but being a Widget will not be distinguished since it has no size or a distinctive color